# Use Kubernetes API and increase rate limit value

Tags: go, kubernetes

Im using the following code

```
kubeconfig = resolveKubeconfig(kubeconfig)
    if kubeconfig == "" {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%s: %w", msgCouldNotCreateClientConfig, ErrLocatingKubeconfig)
    }
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubeconfig)
```

Now I use unstruct to apply resource to the cluster (5 simple deployments)

And I saw that the apply is taking time like starting throttling,

when I change the config to use like

```
config.QPS = 250
```

it works better, and I dont face any issue.

I understand that its related for the rate limit of k8s api with the api server.

two questions:

1. why it happen if I dont apply too much resource
2. I increase the value, is it ok or can make some issue ?

Should I use also Burst?

I didnt find a lot of docs on the QPS and Burst ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in `client-go` the Burst is 10 and QPS is 5
so it should not block you if you just applied several request.

To increase the `Burst` and `OPS` no effect to your application but may create heavy load on the `api-server`.

Comment: Does it make load only for my program, I mean give it a priority if I raise the QPS and when my program finish it will stop the load?

Comment: The `QPS` and `Burst` setting in `client-go` is in your application side, not `api-server` side

Comment: But does it affect the K8S API server ? or just the client-go ?

Comment: Just effect your application(and client-go in your application), for `api-server` if it does not set the restriction on certain client, bandwidth will be cost by the client.